# Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm working with springboot angularsjs and restful.

**my rest controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatestructure/{ch}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody Structurenotification updateStructure(@PathVariable(value="ch") StructureNotificationDto ch) {
    return StructureNotif.update(ch);
}
```

**the button**

```
$scope.addstructure = function() {
      $http.put('/structure/updatestructure/', $scope.element);
};
```

But I get this problem :

> o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound: Request method 'PUT' not supported

Comment: I think this problem could be more related to Java than JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

You have defined your `{ch}` variable as `PathVariable`, and you send it as Request Body. You Mapping accepts URL's like `/structure/updatestructure/abc`,`/structure/updatestructure/efg`, and values `abc` and `efg` would be than passed as strings. In this case your mapping should look like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatestructure/{ch}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody Structurenotification updateStructure(@PathVariable String ch) {    
}
```

But, your are actualli going to send a JSON as request body(assuming from your angular `$http.put(url,data)`).
Your mapping should be then as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatestructure/",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody Structurenotification updateStructure(@RequestBody StructureNotificationDto ch) {
    return StructureNotif.update(ch);
}
```